# How to make simple python generator from nested generator, "Generator in Generator"?

Tags: python, generator

I'm tring to solve "EULER's conjecture on sums of like powers" problem for fun. **Fun**.

[image]

My goal is below.

1. use multicores
2. memory efficiency

I almost finished, But generator part is problem.

my code is below.

```
from pqdm.processes import pqdm # this is parallel package. 
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain
from math import pow

max_iter = 1+4
max_a = 1000
nk_pairs = {
    (combinations_with_replacement(range(1, max_a), r=n), k)
    for k in range(1, max_iter)
    for n in range(1, k+1)
} 
# ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ this line is the problem.

def clear_root(val, k):
    """ define val is k power of integer """
    _ = pow(val, 1/k)
    if int(_) == _:
        return True
    return False

def func(array, k):
    sum_ = sum([pow(x, k) for x in array])
    if clear_root(sum_, k):
        return array, k

pqdm(nk_pairs, func, n_jobs=24)
```

All combinations are generated by generator, but, nested generator doesn't fit for parallel functions.

How can I make this nested generator to un-nested?

Comment: Can you show for a simple example what you want to get as result for `nk_pairs`?

Comment: `return int(_) == _`

Comment: The paper talks about nth powers. You use kth powers. I find that a bit confusing.

Comment: You don't have **any** generator, let alone a nested one. What are you referring to? And what do you mean with "simple" generator?

Comment: "memory efficiency" -- right now it's still queueing tasks here (after 5 minutes, but that might be OS-caused) and the Python process already consumes over a gigabyte. And all this memory usage is not really helping improve performance (like sparing a few kilobytes to cache all the powers, so you don't recalculate that all the time).

Comment: Also, `clear_root` is broken in its current state. Consider that due to floating point rounding errors, the result of `pow(4**3, 1/3)` is actually `3.9999999999999996`. It will return `False`, yet the input is definitely a power of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pqdm` doesn't recognize nested iterators/generators. To make that work you would need to build a single generator as shown below (for sample `max_a = 100`):

```
from pqdm.processes import pqdm # this is parallel package.
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain
from math import pow

max_iter = 1+4
max_a = 100

def nk_pairs_gen():
    for k in range(1, max_iter):
        for n in range(1, k + 1):
            for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, max_a), r=n):
                yield (c, k)

def clear_root(val, k):
    """ define val is k power of integer """
    _ = pow(val, 1/k)
    return int(_) == _

def func(arr, k):
    if clear_root(sum(pow(x, k) for x in arr), k):
        return arr, k

res = pqdm(nk_pairs_gen(), func, n_jobs=12, argument_type='args')
```

---

Note, that `res` would contain a lot of `None` values as returned by `func` function, to filter them out use:

```
res = list(filter(None, pqdm(nk_pairs_gen(), func, n_jobs=12, argument_type='args')))
```

The output:

```
QUEUEING TASKS | : 4598121it [01:34, 48869.83it/s]
PROCESSING TASKS | : 100%|██████████| 4598121/4598121 [11:28<00:00, 6679.72it/s]
COLLECTING RESULTS | : 100%|██████████| 4598121/4598121 [01:09<00:00, 65887.49it/s]
```

---

**Update:**

Considering that `pqdm` might in classical way pass each single combination to a separate process, which is not efficient, a more optimal way would be to yield the entire set of combinations for a given `k` passed to a processing function modified for multiple combinations (run in a separate process). Sample on `max_a = 200`:

```
max_iter = 1+4
max_a = 200

def nk_pairs_gen():
    for k in range(1, max_iter):
        for n in range(1, k + 1):
            yield (combinations_with_replacement(range(1, max_a), r=n), k)

def clear_root(val, k):
    """ define val is k power of integer """
    _ = pow(val, 1/k)
    return int(_) == _

def main_func(combs, k):
    return [(c, k) for c in combs
            if clear_root(sum(pow(x, k) for x in c), k)]

res = list(chain.from_iterable(pqdm(nk_pairs_gen(), main_func, n_jobs=12, argument_type='args')))
print(res[:30])
```

---

```
QUEUEING TASKS | : 10it [00:00, 530.94it/s]
PROCESSING TASKS | : 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:57<00:00,  5.73s/it]
COLLECTING RESULTS | : 100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 202623.38it/s]
[((1,), 1), ((2,), 1), ((3,), 1), ((4,), 1), ((5,), 1), ((6,), 1), ((7,), 1), ((8,), 1), ((9,), 1), ((10,), 1), ((11,), 1), ((12,), 1), ((13,), 1), ((14,), 1), ((15,), 1), ((16,), 1), ((17,), 1), ((18,), 1), ((19,), 1), ((20,), 1), ((21,), 1), ((22,), 1), ((23,), 1), ((24,), 1), ((25,), 1), ((26,), 1), ((27,), 1), ((28,), 1), ((29,), 1), ((30,), 1)]
```

Comment: On Windows with Python 3.7, this still spews out a lot of errors due to missing `if __name__ == '__main__':` for the last line...

Comment: An optimization: `n_jobs=1`. That seems to be ~200 times faster for me.

Comment: So... amusingly, it might be better to leave their "nested generator", the one thing they complain about, as it is. And change their `func` instead. So that each process builds arrays itself instead of expensively having them sent (I think that's what's happening if you use `n_jobs` > 1).

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm already testing that version on `max_a = 1000`, but it doesn't seem to run fast

Comment: Maybe try just 150. That should be enough to find the paper's counterexample.

Comment: Yeah, IMHO it schedules the jobs at too fine a granularity (one iteration of the generator at a time?), which I'd imagine will also involve a lot of overhead in progress reporting.

Comment: Oh, I misread their nk_pairs, I thought it's finer granularity than it is. It only has 10 elements. And likely the "largest" one would dominate the time. So it should be finer than that, but less fine than the current answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy, bigger chunks (combinations) version on `max_a = 200` runs comparatively good, but really starts slow down when progressing `max_a` with  another `+100`s

Comment: I suppose this is not really about how to optimize it, but if you move the `pow(x, k)` from `func` to the inner loop of `nk_pairs_gen`, you avoid a lot of redundant recalculations, and even a naive single-threaded implementation takes slightly below 40% of the original time. | Also, since the conjecture only applies for `n > 2`, the generator only needs to consider `k` in `range(3, max_iter)`. Along the same note, it applies to **sums**, so `n` should start at `2` instead of `1` (avoiding all the false positives, although those were a good indicator of the brokenness of `clear_root`).

Comment: Ah, and since we also only want to provide a counter-example, then there's no point for `n` to run all the way to `k`... so `for n in range(2, k)`.

Comment: Now, if I rewrite `clear_root` to something like this: `return round(pow(val, 1/k))**k == val`, which might not be optimal, but actually returns the right result... I'm at about 2 minutes on a 10 year old CPU (i7-4930k), running single threaded (no pqdm).

Comment: @DanMašek, `round` might not put much accuracy to the result. `int(np.cbrt(7) ** 3) == np.cbrt(7) ** 3` would still give `False` (if OP really considers only integer `kth` root of sum)

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there. I also don't see how that example is relevant -- we're checking whether `val` (the sum) is a `k`th power of some integer, right? I suppose an epsilon compare might be better, this was a clumsy way of avoiding it.